# How to achieve a validation on Master for child's count in Master-Detail relationship without Apex Trigger?

Tags: master-detail

There is a master-detail relationship between two objects and I want to ensure that the master object should not have more than 10 child records. How can we achieve this without using a trigger ?

Answer (score 2):

Create Roll-up summary - COUNT field on Parent object and validation rule

```
If you’re trying to enforce a record limit of 25 on the parent roll-up summary field, create validation rules on your child objects. When you add a child record, your validation rule on the child object can check if the count is already 25 or greater.
```

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&type=5

from documentation - Best Practices

Comment: will this solution be always real-time? As mentioned [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&type=5) _"Calculating roll-up summary field values can take up to 30 minutes, depending on the number of records affected and other factors"_.

Comment: I believe that is about sharing recalculation and owners, currency recalculation, .etc .